# Find all complex solutions to $\sin z = i \sinh z$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I have tried the usual method of expanding into exponentials and letting $t:= e^{z}$ and then solving a polynomial equation. However, in the equation there are some $t^i$ that I don't know how to deal with.

I know that the problem has a solution as Mathematica lists this solutions ($k \in \mathbb{Z}$):

- $(2+2i)\pi k$
- $(1-i)(i\pi + 2 i \pi k)$
- $(1-i)(-\frac{\pi}{2} + 2 \pi k)$
- $(1-i)(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi k)$

I have also proved that the question asked is equivalent to finding all complex solutions of $\sinh{iz}=\sinh{-z}$.

Comment: note that $i\sin iz=\frac{e^{-z}-e^z}{2}=-\sinh z$ so $\sin iz=i \sinh z$ hence the equation is $\sin z=\sin iz$ or $2\sin ((z-iz)/2) \cos ((z+iz)/2)=0$ so either $z-iz=2k\pi$ or $z+iz=\pi +2k\pi$

Comment: @Conrad That should be an answer.

Comment: @J.G. added it, no problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

note that $i\sin iz=\frac{e^{-z}-e^z}{2}=-\sinh z$ so $\sin iz=i \sinh z$ hence the equation is $\sin z=\sin iz$ or $2\sin ((z-iz)/2) \cos ((z+iz)/2)=0$ so either $z−iz=2k\pi$ or $z+iz=π+2k\pi$ and simplifying the cases reduces to $z=(1+i)k \pi$ or $z=(1-i)(\pi/2 +k\pi)$

Answer (score 0):

As $e^z=\cosh z+\sinh z$ and $e^{iz}=cos z+i\sin z$

$$2i(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})=-2(e^z-e^{-z})$$

Now if $e^{iz}=a, e^{-z}=b$

we have $$a-\dfrac1a=b-\dfrac1b \iff a^2b-b=ab^2-a\iff0=ab(a-b)+1(a-b)=(a-b)(ab+1)$$

$$a=b\implies e^{-z}=e^{iz}\iff e^{(1+i)z}=1 \implies(1+i)z=2m\pi i$$

$$ab+1=0\implies ab=-1\iff e^{(1-i)z}=-1\implies(1-i)z=(2n+1)\pi i$$

Comment: Could you explain your first $\implies$ in more detail?

Comment: $b - 1/b = -(a - 1/a)$ doesn't imply $b/a = 1$ (doesn't imply $b/a = -1$ either).

Comment: @J.G., Please find updated version

Comment: @Maxim, Could you please check the latest version

Comment: There is still some confusion with the algebra. The first equation should be $e^{i z} - e^{-i z} = e^{-z} - e^z$.

Comment: @Maxim, Thanks for your observation